How the number of Requests is been counted for a Power automate flow, and how we can reduce it
I have a Child flow named "Set Permissions (Child Flow)", and on some occasions especially at the beginning of each month where the KPI work orders get created i got a message from Microsoft that my flow is running too many actions:-

So i am trying to improve it, but i am not fully sure how the number of requests are actually been counted. for example i did this modification, not sure if it will force my workflow to make less requests:-

Previously inside my flow, I Break the Item Permission inheritance >> Get all Permissions >> loop through all the permissions >> check if the Principle is not for the admin Group >> remove them inside a loop and then reassign it with Read inside another loop , as follow:-





Now i did those changes. Instead of having 2 loops with one action at each loop, i only define one loop that has 2 actions, and that single loop will remove the permission and reassign it with Read + the removed the Condition check, since it is not much needed to give the admin Read on the item, since the admin is the site collection administrator, here is my updated flow:-



so will the modifications which i did reduce the number of requests my flow will do? and how the requests have been counted and will be counted after my modifications? can anyone help me?
Thanks

There doesn't seem to be a limit on the number of Http requests in Power Automate, the problem arises when you have too many loops. You can monitor the number of actions in your flow using the usage analytics on the Details page.

@KarleyZhou-MSFT can you be more specific please? i know the limit is on the number of Actions ,, and those action can generate Http requests... i did not get what you exactly mean?having loops is not the problem by itself, but rather how many Actions those loops will generate.. so in my described scenario ,, did the modification i do will reduce the number of actions the flow will do on each iteration ?
